# Does angular 2.0 alpha work with the components in angular/material Project?

Tags: angular, material-design

I've been trying to get this to work, but haven't been able to. If it's possible, please point to a sample.

Comment: the angular 2 source contains an ongoing material design implementation, that can be built using the main gulp file using build.js.material I believe https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L1275 I saw it working a while ago and it was still in the very early stages

Answer (score 13):

The team is working on a port of Angular Material for 2.0, and you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2_material).

I created a quick demo showing how to use it together with Angular 2:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {MdInput, MdInputContainer} from 'angular2_material/material';

// Defines a new HTML tag <hello-ngconf>
@Component({
    selector: 'material-demo'
})
@View({
    template: `
    <md-input-container>
      <label>Your name</label>
      <input #newname />
    </md-input-container>
    <p>
      Hello, {{newname.value}}
    </p>
    `,
    directives: [MdInputContainer, MdInput]
})
class MaterialDemoComponent {
}

bootstrap(MaterialDemoComponent);
```

See in action in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QtOsjtDvUGuTYmDTmm6f?p=preview).

You can find additional examples in [the angular2 repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/examples/src/material).

Be aware that this is still alpha code and it is not fully functional. For example, I couldn't get MdButton to work because of [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1802).

Comment: Thanks. @urish, Does the current angular-material css work with Angular 2.0?

Comment: I haven't tried this, but even if it does, this use case is not currently supported by the team so I would not recommend it

Comment: Thanks @urish .. For some reason it was not working for me. Here is the working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/vSS7yMroAeTDHALG8eEg?p=preview

Comment: I think stuff changed so urish plunk no longer works. @Shidhin-Cr your plunk works except for the fonts for some reason

Comment: Someone modified the plunk linked above. Here is a working plunk. http://plnkr.co/edit/vSS7yMroAeTDHALG8eEg?p=preview   However, when I copied it,  my atom-typscript kept give the error - cannot find 'angular2_material/material' - even with several modified trials. Looks like special sauce to me.

Comment: What did you do to use it ? There is no npm repo so it's not possible to install the angular2_material with a npm command. I don't know how to add it to my angular 2 application.

Comment: @ShidhinCr Did you mean to put `<h1>{{title}}</h1>` in the app.js of your plunker?

Answer (score 5):

Current version of angular-material will not work with angular 2.0, but i am sure there will be new branch(or version) which will be compatible with angualar 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. Does the current angular-material css work with Angular 2.0?

Comment: This post is now a year old. There have been advancements and angular-material-2 alpha-0 is out, with demos. https://github.com/angular/material2

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I did discover today they have a link in the angular/material README that points to a repository they created specifically for the angular2 target of angular/material: https://github.com/angular/material2

It's still in alpha0.

As a suggestion, perhaps it might help to use something like http://www.getmdl.io/ until material2 gets off the ground. It might allow you to prototype sooner.